# Primary key of type Date causing problems when updating row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, composite-primary-key

We have a table with a composite key (varchar(64) and Date). This has worked fine in our other test environments but in our acceptance test environment (and database) when updating a row we get an error saying no rows were affected. As far as we can tell everything in the environment and the database is the same as any other. The calling client is .NET (using ODP.NET) and the database is Oracle 11g. Any ideas?

Comment: can you include the full oracle version (11.n.n.n) and CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements

Answer (score 1):

Oracle DATE datatype internally stores both DATE and TIME. In case you are updating with a WHERE clause specifying the DATE only, then the time component defaults to midnight time.

Thus the DATE which you are providing for update in WHERE clause, might not match with the stored DATE in the table, because of the time variation.

I think this might be the issue. Can you please verify with it.

If you just want to verify the DATE component without the TIME value in it, then you can use TO_CHAR function to just get it as in here -

UPDATE ... SET ...
WHERE TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') = '10-DEC-2014'

Comment: Oracle recommends "not use the TO_DATE function with a DATE value for the char argument. The first two digits of the returned DATE value can differ from the original char, depending on fmt or the default date format". TO_DATE - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Comment: @michaos I am sorry for this. I actually meant to use TO_CHAR, so as to get only the date component as character. I modified the comment now. Thanks.

Comment: @Manish Forgot to mention we're also using the time component. (In hindsight it probably would have been smarter to use a surrogate.) In any case, it must be some setting that's causing the problem, we just can't figure out what.